# How to use beforeProject in kotlintest?

Tags: kotlin, kotlintest

I've implemented a `TestListener` as follows:

```
object IntegrationTest: TestListener {
    override fun beforeProject() {
        println("integration tests - beforeProject")
    }

    override fun beforeSpec(description: Description, spec: Spec) {
        println("integration tests - beforeSpec")
    }
}
```

And used it in a test:

```
class SimpleTest: StringSpec() {

    override fun listeners() = listOf(IntegrationTest)

    init {
        "it - 1" {
            println("it - 1")
        }

        "it - 2" {
            println("it - 2")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `integration tests - beforeProject` is never printed in the output.

The result is:

```
integration tests - beforeSpec
it - 1
it - 2
```

I tried it in intellij and using gradle CLI. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`beforeProject` has to run before any tests are discovered, otherwise it's not really before the *project* but would kind of be "before any tests have executed" (The difference might not be important in your use class, but KotlinTest mantains the distinction).

Therefore overriding that method in a listener that's added to a test class doesn't do anything (as you have seen).

So instead you need to add your listener to `ProjectConfig` which is project wide configuration. You do this by subclassing `AbstractProjectConfig` and putting it in a special package name, like this:

package io.kotlintest.provided

```
object ProjectConfig : AbstractProjectConfig() {
  // add listeners here
}
```

See full docs here:
https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/blob/master/doc/reference.md#project-config

Comment: Where exactly to create this package - io.kotlintest.provided in root or under src ?

Comment: src/test is fine yes

Comment: how to inject the datasource into ProjectConfig beforeProject?